# custom php.ini file in subfolder causing issues with $_SESSIONS variables

Tags: session-variables, php

I have a sub-folder with two files. The first is email.php, with a form that user can send me an email. It also has a captcha-like script to prevent spam, and uses `$_SESSION[foo]` variables. The second is upload.php, which allows registered users to upload files. Both files worked fine. Now I need to increase the upload_max_filesize from the base 2MB for upload.php. My host does not provide access to main php.ini, but recommend that I create a custom php.ini file in this subfolder. So I created:

php.ini

```
upload_max_filesize = 10M ;
post_max_size = 10M ;
```

I now get the errors `Warning: include() [function.include]: Filename cannot be empty` and `Warning: include() [function.include]: Failed opening '' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php')` when I submit the form/captcha on email.php.

```
$_SESSION[foo]=$_GET[bar]; 
else  $_SESSION[foo]="foobar.php";
include($_SESSION['foo']);
```

I found that `$_SESSION[foo]` is empty even with the `else`. After some research I found that when I ran `phpinfo()` that `session.save_path` was `no value` (the original was /tmp). So now

php.ini

```
upload_max_filesize = 10M ;
post_max_size = 10M ;
session.save_path = /home/foobar/tmp ;
```

But I am still getting the error. If I remove the php.ini file from this folder, then the form script on email.php works just fine, but I am back to `upload_max_filesize` = 2MB for upload.php. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an issue with CGI PHP setups where the server `php.ini` directives do not cascade into custom configurations.

I've written about this extensively here - http://blog.philipbrown.id.au/2009/08/php-suexec-and-custom-php-ini-files/

---

> $_SESSION[foo]=$_GET[bar]; 
>   else  $_SESSION[foo]="foobar.php";
>   include($_SESSION['foo']);

I'm a bit confused by this snippet. Not only is it invalid (no `if` statement, array indexes not quoted) but highly insecure.

Comment: I copied the snippet and missed the first part with the `if` statement and the array, my mistake sorry. I just did the cron job that you recommended on your blog. This worked perfectly, and now my `phpinfo()` is correct and both pages are working correctly. Thank you.

Comment: @Sean You're still blindly including a file based directly on a query parameter. This is *never* a good idea

Comment: I am novice, so I appreciate your help. I inherited this script, as I have taken over managing a website for a non-profit. Here is the script with the beginning of that query `if (is_file($_GET[bar]) and dirname($_GET[bar])=='.' ) $_SESSION[foo]=$_GET[bar]; else $_SESSION[foo]="foobar.php"; include($_SESSION[foo]);`

Comment: @Sean That looks a little better but it's still a direct relationship between the query parameter and included file. I'd recommend maintaining an array of key to filename associations. The query parameter can reference the key and you use that to lookup the filename.

Comment: Is there any better way that doesn't involve a cron job?