# PHP session resets when switching through tabs on the same domain

Tags: php, session

I have a website (www.mysite.com) with a private backend (www.mysite.com/admin)

When I'm adding content to the site in the admin area and switch back and forth between tabs in the same browser window to see the content I'm editing, my session is getting expired/ended/terminated and I'm redirected to the login page again.

I have used the same code many-many times before on many web sites (this is a CMS I've made by myself) without a problem. The only thing I can think of is that this particular website is hosted on a different web server and maybe it's a matter of a php.ini setting or server configuration. Any ideas?

Comment: Any chance you're on a shared/clustered webservice?

Comment: It's probably a shared hosting account, how can I tell for sure? And if I am, do you have a suggestion for me?

Comment: I meant shared as in many servers, shared with others doesnt matter, clustered matters, as by default PHP writes to a temp file on the local box, if a different box responds that session doesnt exist - you would need to work it into a DB based session

Comment: Do you have a `session_start()` statement with no check if the session already started?

Comment: Yes, I do. I believe the error began to occur when my client had his site moved to another web server so it must be a server configuration thing. I've used the very same code so many times on many servers and I never had a similar problem.

Comment: Are you accesing those sites behind a proxy, eg. you edit them frow your workplace and your employer has a proxy server to access internet.. is it the case?

Comment: No proxies, just a simple broadband connection.

Comment: Have you checked errors using error_reporting(-1);? It should show most obvious errors, file access errors and similar. If there are no errors and warning, it's hard work to quess - without access to your site. This is like Sherlock Holmes -case, you get minor information  and every piece of information have to self ask.

Comment: [link](www.mysite.com) or [link](www.mysite.com/admin) gives not hints :( What is the real url?

Comment: @bikey77 Real URl and providing your code would help.

Answer (score 1):

A few things to check:

- `session.cookie_lifetime` setting - Possibly too short; 0 is the default and keeps the cookie until the browser closes
- `session.cookie_path` setting - You'll want this to be '/'
- Session storage - Make sure the session data is being written.
- Explicitly call `session_close()` if your sessions are stored in a database. That will ensure they are written before your objects and database resources are destroyed.
- If serving through any sort of proxy, check for any changed header information.
- If caching, check your dynamic pages (requiring sessions) are being served by your web app and not the cache.
- If testing with your local /etc/hosts, first clear your cookies so the new server's cookies are fresh and don't conflict.
- Confirm in your browser that the cookie is in fact being stored. Maybe it's not actually coming back in the header.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. The settings are exactly as you mention them in php.ini
I can see session variables being registered and assigned values but when I switch through tabs, the session gets unset, strange but it happens.

Comment: @bikey77 - Are you able to view the cookie details within your browser?  I know Chrome has this feature.

Comment: I've added 4 more suggestions of what to look at.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked your browser cookies? (the actual client-side ones?) or tried your luck with another browser? It may sound a bit strange, but I had a similar problem and in my case it had to do with these cookies. It may be worth figuring out because of your odd problem. As you might know the phpsession value is stored in that cookie and so is the domain. 
Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

This could be a result of several things, but my first instinct is to check and see if the session cookies are expiring very quickly. Sometimes server headers may change expiry values. You may also want to check the cache headers being sent by the server. If you are using asynchronous functionality on the admin area, it is possible that somehow the server is changing the expiry of cached files which could affect this.

I am eager to see the solution to this.

Comment: I'd like to see the outcome aswell :)

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem like this before. I was just uploaded a site from my localhost to a remote host, and I haven't change the nameservers yet. The hosting company provided me with a temporary url to be able to see my website. The problem was that this url was like this https://server_name.grserver.gr:8443/sitepreview/http/my_site.gr/, the result was that any browser didn't accepted the session cookie because I didn't had an SSL sertificate so the sessions didn't worked at all. I browsed a little the plesk panel and I found an other temporary url that was using http protocol, with this everything was ok. So if you are using https try to check if you have a problem with your ssl sertificate (for expample if it has expired). You said the problem occurs when you login in the admin page, do you switch then to https?

Comment: It's not a matter of https, I'm not using ssl or https on the site.

Comment: Try to add this line after every session_start(); in every page of your site: echo session_id();. First you have tou be 100% sure that the problem is only with the admin pages. If the value changes in every request it means that the session expired or the browser didn't send the session cookie back. Also if you use firefox this addon will help a lot https://addons.mozilla.org/el/firefox/addon/edit-cookies/ with debugging (The value of PHPSESSID is the session_id). Good luck!

Comment: Also you can try to change the default path that php stores the session data, if you do that and then access the folder via ftp you will see files with filenames that contain the session_id. If with every request a new file is generated then again that means a new session has been created because the previews expiered or browser din't send the session cookie. And at last check if you are able to access the PHPSESSID cookie using "echo $_COOKIE['PHPSESSID']";

Answer (score 0):

There could be several reasons. As there is no code or no details about the site provided , I am assuming that the problem might be if you are using `htpasswd`. If u are using `htaccess` authentication, then your session gets destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

From experience, I can tell you a few things.

First, sessions need to be started with

```
session_start();
```

At the top of every page you want to use sessions.

Next, to save session data, you need to call another function to tell php that you are saving stored data. That function is

```
Session_write_close();
```

That function is needed on the bottom of the page when you are finished writing data to a session and want it saved for later use.

With those two combined, that should allow you to properly write to a session, save the data you entered into it, and access it later on your site.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been found after reading [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5561540/custom-php-ini-file-in-subfolder-causing-issues-with-sessions-variables).

I had a custom php.ini in the root dir and apparently it was interfering with the $_SESSION. I don't know why but after deleting it everything works fine.

At first it seemed as if the problem was opening pages located in different sub-folders in several browser tabs however it narrows down to a sub-folders issue and the fact that the $_SESSION wasn't accessible across them.

I'd like to thank everyone that put some time into trying to help me figure this out.