# php.ini breaks session variables

Tags: php

I contacted my host to increase our upload_max_filesize and was told to use a php.ini file in the script directory.

However, the mere presence of a php.ini file (whether empty or with instructions) erases all session variables.

This is my desired php.ini file:

```
max_input_time = 1500
memory_limit = 100M
post_max_size = 75M
upload_max_filesize = 75M
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting it in the webroot so the settings may apply globally?

Comment: Yes, I did try that. My host has disallowed that. Custom php.ini may only reside in script folder.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, this question solves my problem.  Please close as an exact duplicate of [custom php.ini file in subfolder causing issues with $_SESSIONS variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5561540/custom-php-ini-file-in-subfolder-causing-issues-with-sessions-variables?rq=1)